# Maven project. Two POMs, one for dev, one for publishing

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am working on a library that uses Maven. The current pom.xml file has a lot of stuff related to tests, reports, etc.

I now want to publish a release of this library to a private Maven repository. I need to supply a much simpler pom.xml file to the repository.

How is this managed? Can you generate the simpler pom file from the one used in development?

Comment: What do you mean with "I need to supply a much simpler pom.xml file to the repository"? Whose restriction is this?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html 

Check at the bottom of the basic sample.  

<!--
  NOT ALLOWED: (see FAQ)
  <repositories></repositories>
  <pluginRepositories></pluginRepositories>
  -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set up your private Maven repository to mirror/ proxy all required repositories and pluginRepositories
- Configure your settings.xml to redirect all requests to your private Maven repository
- Remove the repositories and pluginRepositories from your POM

-> no separate POM needed for deployment

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise pom simply is an XML. You can apply an XSLT wrapper to sort out the entries you want to change and wrap the maven build scripts within some batch commands.

Comment: The whole point of using a system like maven is to escape from build script hell. Now you are suggesting to wrap maven in a build script???